# onSaveInstanceState gets called twice on Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, database

I am working on a Android application where in I want to save the information entered into the  textviews of the activity in the database whenever the phone call arrives, orientation of the app is changed, etc.

I am using this code to save the information entered into the textview by the user.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        save();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On save state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**Problem :**

Whenever my phone orientation is changed the `onSaveInstanceState` method is called twice. Can anyone explain me the reason for this.

Because it is called twice, `save()` also get called twice and I have duplicate entries into my database table - which is not good.

I cannot use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest file to deal with orientation change. As it makes the ads disappear when user changes landscape to portrait.

`onSaveInstanceState` is called only once when phone call is received :)

**Note : save() is also called onBackPressed() method**

Please assist !

Comment: is save() only called in the onSaveInstanceState() method?

Comment: Nope, it is also called onBackPressed() method

Comment: I just want to make sure that all data is saved in database when ever activity goes in background, destroyed or any other interuption

Comment: Are you sure it's called twice on the same activity instance? If you have more than activity in the task, all of them will be recreated. The how and when has changed throughout Android versions but it could be that two separate activities are getting recreated.

Comment: Data of A form gets inserted into A table but when I am on activity A, and I change the orientation the app. My goes to the main activity and there are duplicate entries in table A :(

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that what you really want to do is saving persistent data in a database. If so, `onSaveInstanceState` is not your method.

`onSaveInstanceState` is used to save the temporary state of the activity to be able to recreate it exactly as it was on the `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState`. The default implementation already saves/restores most of the UI standard views and if you override it probably you will want to keep calling the default implementation and then save/restore the additional values. By the way, the values are stored on the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) which basically provides a way to store/retrieve key-value pairs.

If you really want to save persistent state, you should do it on the `onPause` method that is part of the lifecycle of the `Activity`. Note what the [activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) says:

> Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

To avoid the problem with duplicate rows, you just need to check if the record you are trying to save already exists or not (you need some kind of unique identifier for this) and then create or update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was getting called twice when returning from *camera intent + orientation change*. Then i ended up writing *Singleton Manager class* to save and restore my variables whenever i want. This class holds your variables in `static final` variables and you should clear it when you no longer use it.